# Disable Screen Orientation Dynamically In Android(Java)

Tags: java, android, screen, android-manifest, screen-rotation

I want to lock my application to portrait mode for all the activities. I know this can be done by setting `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in activity tag in manifest. but I have lots of activities, so I was wondering is there any way to do it on application level either by some xml tag in manifest or in code anyhow, so I wont have to define it in all the activity tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Or

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Use this method in the `BaseActivity`. And extend this activity for every other activity in your application.